# Conveying "Pardon my French"

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

> "Pardon my French" or "Excuse my French" is a common English language phrase ostensibly disguising profanity as words from the French language. The phrase is uttered in an attempt to excuse the user of profanity, swearing, or curses in the presence of those offended by it, under the pretense of the words being part of a foreign language.

> Although the phrase is often used without any explicit or implicit intention of insulting the French people or language, it can nevertheless be perceived as offensive and belittling by Francophone speakers.

> However, most users of the term intend no such belittlement, but rather a light-hearted way of apologizing on-the-fly for having used a somewhat profane comment. In other words, it can be (and usually is) used as a very effective oral English device to indicate that the speaker does not intend to escalate the general level of profanity use.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pardon_my_French

See also: https://blog.courrierinternational.com/croquis-d-angleterre/2018/08/24/origines-de-lexpression-excuse-my-french/

How could one convey "pardon my French"? For instance for French leave there is filer à l'anglaise. Is there a language that can be used in French in the turn "excuse-moi mon X" (where X is the language)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Passez-moi [l'expression](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/passez-moi_l%E2%80%99expression)/[le mot](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/passez-moi_le_mot)* servant à « atténuer (ou bien au contraire de mettre en valeur) le caractère potentiellement choquant de l’expression qui suit » (Wiktionnaire) précède normalement ce qui choque mais Larousse l'a reformulé et employé après : « [...], if you'll [pardon](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/pardon%5B1%5D) the expression or my French (very informal) : *[...], **si vous voulez bien me passer l'expression*** » ([Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/pardon/600396)). On trouve aussi « *passez-moi l'expression* » comme suggestion de traduction sur [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pardon_my_French#Translations). C'est certainement utile...

Comment: > He's a bastard, if you'll pardon the expression OR my French (very informal)    c'est un salaud, si vous voulez bien me passer l'expression ; c'est nickel:-)! Merci !

Answer (score 3):

"[Excusez mon langage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=excusez+mon+langage&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexcusez%20mon%20langage%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cexcusez%20mon%20langage%3B%2Cc0)" is a common way to express that ([ref.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22excusez+mon+langage%22&lr=lang_fr&safe=active&tbs=lr:lang_1fr,sbd:1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi05brXndHuAhUyzYUKHVj1BU4QpwUIJA&biw=1920&bih=1005&dpr=1)).

([ref. 1](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Fc15zaAdmbMC&pg=PT167&dq=%22excusez+mon+langage%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwivqr7ondHuAhUCfBoKHbARD1YQ6AEwBnoECCEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22excusez%20mon%20langage%22&f=false))  Non, aucune chance. Alors, excusez mon langage, mais... Putain! Qu'est-ce

([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=LG-7UfalwigC&pg=PT30&dq=%22excusez+mon+langage%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwivqr7ondHuAhUCfBoKHbARD1YQ6AEwB3oECCAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22excusez%20mon%20langage%22&f=false)) Mais s'être tapé le trajet jusqu'ici pour me demander de localiser quelqu'un, alors qu'il savait pertinemment dans quel état m'avait mise ce travail merdique (excusez mon langage) !

([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=28ikSpqMXacC&pg=PT66&dq=%22excusez+mon+langage%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwivqr7ondHuAhUCfBoKHbARD1YQ6AEwCHoECCUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22excusez%20mon%20langage%22&f=false)) . salopard de premier ordre (excusez mon langage). Depuis, je me suis toujours donné un mal de chien pour vérifier que les enfants que je localisais étaient d'accord pour l'être.